# how to filter data branch_id(R001) can't display when user input branch_id(R002) can display message box

Tags: flutter, filter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts6AS.png)
hi everyone, how to filter branch_id (R002) only can display and except branch_id (R001) display error

Future _showDialogError() async {
return showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return AlertDialog(
title: const Text('Data Article Tidak Ada'),
content: const Text('Pastikan Nomor Delivery Benar'),
actions: [
// buttonSave(context)
TextButton(
onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add-item-bdg'),
child: const Text('OK'),
),
],
);
},
);
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have data with the branch_id variable. where branch_id contains R001 and R002. How do I do the R002 filter only appear? R001 does not display